# Remove duplicated Intellisense suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm writing extension that provides CompletionItems to VSCode CSS Intellisense. The issue is that some completions are already being provided to Intellisense by internal VSCode completion providers resulting in showing same complitions twice.

What I need is to remove those duplications. How can I achieve this without messing with css language-server?

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

VS Code shows suggestions from all extensions that provide suggestions. It is not possible for your extension to disable the suggestions from another extension: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/63004

You could try:

- Tell users to disable the built-in css extension.
- Have your extension register a new language and a new completion provider for that language.